# Androidstudio to Kotlin to Swift?

Tags: java, swift, kotlin

I'm working on a project whereby we're creating an app for people to call/message one another.

We're currently developing in Androidstudio, java, but even after we've launched the app, it seems that most of our interested users are on iOS instead.

Is it possible for us to convert Java > Kotlin and use Kotlin Native for our iOS app? I mean, if it's possible we'd like to use a way that wouldn't need us to use too much Swift, since we're a bunch of undergrads who's doing this on interest and we haven't developed in Swift before.

Seems like there are certain projects that are multi-platform so far, but I'm kinda really skeptical about the possibility of us doing so, even though most of our code are written in web.

I'm sorry I'm not that well versed in programming or if this question has been asked before, I'm still kinda new to programming and everything.

I'll really appreciate it if you'd so kindly answer this question! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kotlin/Native for your iOS app and not write any Swift, but you still need to change all of your UI code so that it uses the iOS UI framework and not the Android framework. This conversion needs to be done manually; there's no automated tool for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try out [Flutter](https://flutter.io/) if you want to have one code base for both Android and iOS?